# ValueError: Unknown protobuf attr type <class 'dict'> when tried to put a nested dict/entity

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to `put` a nested `entity/dict` into datastore using `Python`,

```
metadata_row = dict()
metadata_row['batch_id'] = str(uuid1())
metadata_row['table_ok'] = True
metadata_row['table_name'] = 'metadata'
metadata_row['num_rows'] = 1
metadata_row['violations'] = []
metadata_row['errors'] = []

metadata_row['time'] = {}
metadata_row['time']['total_time'] = 82.42656564712524
metadata_row['time']['mod1'] = 5.940682411193848
metadata_row['time']['mod2'] = 19.16786551475525
metadata_row['time']['mod3'] = 31.617812633514404
metadata_row['time']['mod4'] = 0.00038933753967285156
metadata_row['time']['mod5'] = 53.35780310630798

with self.client.transaction():

    entities = [Entity(self.client.key('metadata')) for i in range(len([metadata_row]))]

    for entity, update_dict in zip(entities, [metadata_row]):
        entity.update(update_dict)

    self.client.put_multi(entities)
```

I tested it by using `datastore emulator`, but I got the following error,

```
ValueError: Unknown protobuf attr type <class 'dict'>
```

I am wondering how to fix the issue. I am also wondering does `datastore` natively support nested dictionary in that one doesn't have to create an `entity` for the inner dictionary, i.e. `time` in this case.

UPDATE. I added an inner entity in `metadata_row` for key `time` to solve the problem.

```
client = datastore.Client()
metadata_row['time'] = datastore.Entity(key=client.key('time'))

metadata_row['time']['total_time'] = 82.42656564712524
metadata_row['time']['mod1'] = 5.940682411193848
metadata_row['time']['mod2'] = 19.16786551475525
metadata_row['time']['mod3'] = 31.617812633514404
metadata_row['time']['mod4'] = 0.00038933753967285156
metadata_row['time']['mod5'] = 53.35780310630798

# code for put_multi()
```

Comment: not 100% sure, but I suspect the values in the dict should be in the accepted types (from https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#properties_and_value_types), which don't include dicts. Maybe json.dumps the dict value and store it as a string?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I have also tried `json.dumps`, it works as well, maybe slightly better than adding an inner `entity` for the inner dictionary.

Comment: Facing the same issue when using json.dumps. I think we have to convert nested values to an "Embedded entity"

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(obj, client, key):
"""
:param obj: dict
:param client: datastore client
:param key: Generated as client.key("your_table", "your_key")
:return: datastore.Entity
"""
if isinstance(obj, list):
    return [convert(item, client, None) for item in obj]
elif isinstance(obj, dict):
    entity = datastore.Entity(key)
    for key in obj:
        entity[key] = convert(obj[key], client, None)
    return entity
else:
    return obj
```

Please do suggest any improvements or alternatives as Google Cloud Datastore currently doesn't suggest a way to convert a JSON to an Entity.